# issue passing geolocation coords to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, geocoding

first i made a NSString with the address i need

```
NSString *bldgAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", listingsDisplayed.ADDRESS1, listingsDisplayed.TOWN, listingsDisplayed.ZIPCODE];
```

then i called LMGeocoder [Github Link](https://github.com/lminhtm/LMGeocoder)

```
[[LMGeocoder sharedInstance] geocodeAddressString:bldgAddress service:kLMGeocoderGoogleService completionHandler:^(LMAddress *address , NSError *error) {
 if (address && !error) {
 _latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", address.coordinate.latitude];
 _longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", address.coordinate.longitude];
 } else {
 NSLog(@"%@", error);
 }}];
```

it works fine up to here, _lat and _long are declared in my .h file and the values are assigned respectively

```
cell.lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", _latitude, _longitude];
```

issue start when i try to load that data into the cell, it shows (null),(null). 
i dont understand why the values disappear, any help would be greatly appreciated

---

Edit:
Code that worked  thanks to @dhanush

```
    __block UILabel *currentLAbel = cell.lat;
[[LMGeocoder sharedInstance] geocodeAddressString:bldgAddress service:kLMGeocoderGoogleService completionHandler:^(LMAddress *address , NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (address && !error) {
            listingsDisplayed.Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", address.coordinate.latitude];
            listingsDisplayed.Longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", address.coordinate.longitude];

            currentLAbel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", listingsDisplayed.Latitude, listingsDisplayed.Longitude];
            cell.lat = currentLAbel;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    });
}];
```

---

Comment: set the text inside the block. This won't work if you are doing outside the block.     use the following inside your block

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Assign the value.
    });

Comment: I've wrapped my code in that dispatch line you sent me, it still shows up as null. just to verify, can you confirm i did it right? http://pastebin.com/fvcYKLKB

Comment: NO. Dispatch should be inside your block. And the give the value for the Text inside the Dispatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
    UILabel *currentLAbel = cell.lat;
    [[LMGeocoder sharedInstance] geocodeAddressString:bldgAddress service:kLMGeocoderGoogleService completionHandler:^(LMAddress *address , NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    if (address && !error) {
        listingsDisplayed.Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", address.coordinate.latitude];
        listingsDisplayed.Longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", address.coordinate.longitude];

        currentLAbel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", listingsDisplayed.Latitude, listingsDisplayed.Longitude];
        cell.lat = currentLabel;

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
     });
  }];
```

You should always do UI Changes in Main thread. Initially Those values are null. Once you got those values you can set it inside the block. CurrentLabel will help to get the particular label if you are scrolling the table. try with cell.lat. if it is not working use the current label.

Comment: i had to make some changes to your code but i got it to work, thanks a lot @dhanush

Answer (score 0):

You are getting lat & long in block...that is asynchronous so that is not executed on main thread.

You set the lat & long value before you get its value from block. That's why you are getting null value.

You put breakpoint and track flow of execution, you will get the idea.

Good luck !! :)

Comment: i think i  see what you mean now, the rest of the code has no idea that the block code exists correct?

Comment: Yes correct, but make sure that  the block must execute before you use lat & long value(according to your code lat & long are NSString not a float ).